# AIR Embeded SWF says it's a function

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, air, externalinterface

I am working on an AIR HTML app that needs to display a live stream from a media server on the localhost. My colleague created a Flash app for me that connects to the stream and displays the video and used [ExternalInterface.addCallback](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html) to expose the controls of player (ie. start, stop, etc.). However, once I embed it into the AIR HTML app

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0"
WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240" id="player" ALIGN="">
    <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="../swf/player.swf">
    <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE=high>
    <EMBED src="../swf/player.swf" quality=high WIDTH="320" HEIGHT="240"
        NAME="player" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```

The JavaScript console in AIR tells me that document['player'] is  function, but that document['player'].startStream() (one of the functions he exposed with ExternalInterface) is not defined.

It works fine when it's in its own HTML file, but breaks down in the AIR app. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that the ExternalInterface call has already taken place when you're trying to access it?

Comment: I assumed the interpreter added those as soon as the SWF file was loaded. Is this not correct?

Comment: How do you know the file is already loaded? Is the swf calling a function on the page that says it is loaded?

Comment: No. we wait until the window triggers the air.Event.COMPLETE to even show show the window. So this assumes that the SWF is loaded. Also, when querying the <object> element in the console it shows that it is a function (ie. typeof obj == 'function').

Comment: Amy, thank you for your comments. I think you were right. Although in the ended I ended up using JWPlayer.